# How to convert from Observable<List<X>> to Observable<List<Y>>, using a function that takes X as parameter & returns Observable<Y>

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a method that emits a list of user ids, indefinitely (not finite).

```
Observable<List<String>> getFriendUserIds()
```

And another method that returns `Account` data for a specific user id.

```
Observable<Account> getAccount(String userId)
```

I need to get the `Account` data for all the user ids returned by the getFriendUserIds() method, grouped together in a list corresponding to the user id list.

Basically, I need the following, preferably in a non-blocking way.

```
Observable<List<String>> // infinite stream
===> *** MAGIC + getAccount(String userId) ***  
===> Observable<List<Account>> // infinite stream
```

Example:

```
["JohnId", "LisaId"]---["PaulId", "KimId", "JohnId"]------["KimId"]

===>

[<JohnAccount>, <LisaAccount>]---[<PaulAccount>, <KimAccount>, <JohnAccount>]------[<KimAccount>]
```

Ordering is not important but the `List<Account>` must contain `Account`s corresponding to every user id present in `List<String>`.

**Note that this question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035090/rxjava-fetch-every-item-on-the-list), but with additional requirements to group the resulting items back in a list.

Comment: Simply apply `toList` to the flow you discovered in that question's answer.

Comment: @akarnokd But `toList` will convert it to `Single`, and has additional requirements for the source `Observable` to be finite. `getFriendUserIds()` is an infinite source.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the available operators of RxJava - it will save you a lot of time. In this case, you'd need `take(1)` to limit the source and `toObservable()` to convert back to `Observable`.

Comment: @akarnokd I edited the question, please take another look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Observable<List<Account>> accountsList = getFriendUserIds()
.take(1)
.flatMapIterable(list -> list)
.flatMap(id -> getAccount(id))
.toList()
.toObservable();
```

or this:

```
Observable<List<Account>> accountsList = getFriendUserIds()
.flatMapSingle(list -> 
     Observable.fromIterable(list)
     .flatMap(id -> getAccount(id))
     .toList()
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but the 1st solution will take only the 1st element (["JohnId", "LisaId"] in the example), return the Accounts in a list ([<JohnAccount>, <LisaAccount>]) and **complete**. I am looking for an output stream that **never completes**.

Comment: Second solution is the one I was looking for! Thanks for the help and respect for your work with RxJava!