# RxJava + Kotlin - Using one observable in the creation of another

Tags: java, asynchronous, kotlin, reactive

I am trying to figure out how to use the result of one observable in another.
I have a service call which returns `Observable<List<User>>` and after that I have another service call where I want to use the id of each user (`user.getId()`) in the list of the previous observable to create a list of ids `List<Int>`. Then this list of int will be passed to the second service call. How can I achieve this?

I hope the question makes sense. Let me know if I need to clarify myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `flatMap`. `flatMap` is an operator, where you can emit another observable based on the item of an Observable.

```
val obs: Observable<List<User>>
obs.flatMap { users: List<User> -> 
    serviceWhichEmitsObservable.doMagic(users)
}
```

[flatMap-Operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)

If you want the users separately, you can convert the Observable> -> Obsersvable with fromIterable. See this answer: [RxJava - fetch every item on the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035090/rxjava-fetch-every-item-on-the-list)

```
val obs: Observable<List<User>>
obs
    .flatMap { users: List<User> -> Observable.fromIterable(users)
    .flatMap { user: User -> serviceWhichEmitsObservable.doMagic(user) }
```

After rereading your question, I think what you want is this: `List<User>` -> `List<Integer>` and pass this list to a service. You have to map the list first. This has nothing todo with RX. Nonetheless:

```
val obs: Observable<List<User>>
obs
    .map { users: List<User> -> users.map { it.id } }
    .flatMap { userIds: List<Integer> -> serviceWhichEmitsObservable.doMagic(userIds) }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Would this line `obs
    .map { users: List<User> -> users.map { it.id } }
    .flatMap { userIds: List<Integer> -> serviceWhichEmitsObservable.doMagic(userIds) }` return the observable from the second service call

Comment: Also, I have one more question. Assuming we still have the first service call. But then I just want to use the result (the list of user ids) in a normal method, rather than service call. How would this change?

Comment: Yes it would - thats what `flatMap` is here for. `map` maps an item to another item (`List<User> -> List<Integer>`), `flatMap` allows you return an Observable for a given item (`List<User> -> Observable<Something>`). If you want to use the list outside an observable chain you have to `subscribe` to the observable. I would suggest to create a small workspace where you can play around with RX and learn to understand it.

Comment: On SO its common to accept an answer then rather say "thanks" since thank yous pollute the comments/posts.

Comment: Is this causing serviceWhichEmitsObservable to execute on different thread or same thread as obs? I feel like it does on a different one - is there a way to force it to execute on same thread